# custom rom with only selected apps and no play store

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, custom-roms, uninstallation

I'd like to restrict my mobile usage to a few apps only (basically phone, contacts, camera, google photo, whatsapp) and disallow installation of new apps and especially remove all browsers from the phone.

Background: I'd like to use this android phone to "tune off" and be only available for the urgent things.

Now: is it possible to build a custom rom which only the selected apps? Or would it be easier to just root the phone and install the core apps such as play store and chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Install/trim whatever apps you want, then kill PackageInstaller either by using apps like TitaniumBackup (freezing it) or by deleting it altogether.

Back up and have a try - I haven't tried it myself, but that's the trick some of my local forum members have been using for a while